# Robospice caching when exception occured

Tags: android, json, caching, robospice

I wan't to achieve next.

Depends on json content deside put or not to put data to Robospice Cache.
Sometimes data returned from the server is not valid. For example our authorization token goes off time. So we shouldn't cache this response.

But i can't find API which can help me to solve this trouble. 
Here is how i am using requests now:

```
getSpiceManager().execute(getRequestCreator().getAllCategories(), getRequestCreator().getLastCacheKey(),
                DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE * 120, new JSONCategoryListener(mCategories));
```

So the actual response is normal (status 200), but json content is telling me about exception.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want to get? It is right behavior for server. Server returns 200, means that request is successful. But it not guarantee, that wasn't some internal error of 'business logic' on server, such as not valid data or anything else.

**EDITED**

May be you can use your custom error handler:

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
        @Override public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
            //check response on errors
        }
    }
```

And in createRestAdapterBuilder():

```
new RestAdapter.Builder()..setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler());
```

**EDITED 2**

You can implement in your robospice service method putDataInCache(Object cacheKey, T data), and in your listener check errors in content, and if no error then add it to cache, or remove it from cache

Comment: Yes. your example is right. So i don't want to cache this response from the server. I want to decide should i put response to cache depends on content returned to me by the server.

Comment: @Anatol, sorry, but I think to do it impossible using robospice. The only way  is implement your own cache.

Comment: You can try to implement it using DiskLruCache from Jake Wharton: https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache

Comment: Thanks. I decided to do next.
I am removing data from cache in my onSuccess() Listener, depending on actual content. I will vote up your response to this question but i wait for other simple ideas like yours.

Comment: @Anatol, of course your idea is very good. Thanks for response